# Find the value: $\int_{0}^{π/6}\ 4\sin^{2}xdx$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

**Solving:** $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} 4\sin^2(x)dx$

This is my work

[image]
but I can not seem to get to the answer $\frac{1}{6}(2\pi-3\sqrt{3})$. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please consider typesetting your attempt using mathjax

Comment: @P.J I will try but there iare so many attempts I don't know how to write it all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have the following identity: $\operatorname{cos}(2x) = 1 - 2\operatorname{sin}^2(x)$. Therefore, $4\operatorname{sin}^2(x) = 2(1 - \operatorname{cos}(2x))$.

$$\begin{aligned}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}4\operatorname{sin}^2(x) dx &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}2(1 - \operatorname{cos}(2x)) dx\\ &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}2 dx - \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}2\operatorname{cos}(2x)dx\\ &= 2x|^{\frac{\pi}{6}}_0 - \frac{2\operatorname{sin}(2x)}{2}\vert^{\frac{\pi}{6}}_0\\&=2\cdot\left(\frac{\pi}{6} - 0  \right) - \left[ \operatorname{sin}\left(2\cdot \frac{\pi}{6}\right)  - \operatorname{sin}\left(2\cdot 0\right)\right] \\ &=\frac{\pi}{3} - \operatorname{sin}\left( \frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: The way you solved it made it so easy thank you!